# Does Google WebRTC support Cisco Open H.264?

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, h.264

Knowing the fact that Cisco has its h.264 codec made as open source I wanted to add it to the Android WebRTC SDK. I tried to create custom `VideoEncoder` using the webRTC API but I found that the choice of the codec is made by its name. The `SoftwareVideoEncoderFactory` class returns a class which represents the specific codec based on `VideoCodecInfo` name: [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/SoftwareVideoEncoderFactory.java). In my case, I did it like that:

```
    VideoCodecInfo codecInfo = new VideoCodecInfo("H264", getDefaultH264Params(false));
    SoftwareVideoEncoderFactory softwareVideoEncoderFactory = new SoftwareVideoEncoderFactory();
    softwareVideoEncoderFactory.createEncoder(codecInfo);
```

then added it to my PeerConnectionFactory. Unfortunately, as I suppose the webRTC library doesn't know where the binary with open h264 is.

The question is: do I need to create my own class which will support Open H.264 and then re-build the webRTC library? Would be great if that won't be the case and the API would have an option to make this but I cannot find it.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29355646/7649582

Comment: Thanks @Dhanshri I read this already but that answer is from 2015. I thought something changed since then

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC (https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src) supports h264 using openH264. but it needs to be build for target platform. For Android is has been build in chrome or chromium but not on the Android SDK. so you can't have openH264 using Android SDK. you need to build WebRTC for android yourself and then add the wrapper class to call the native apis. You can use WebRTC JS API on a web application thou.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any advice on how to do that?

Comment: building webrtc for andoid is not straight forward. and I couldn't do it by myself. I reach out a friend and he got me the binary files. i recommend you to read this page (https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) and try to find the SO binary file from specialized professionals. check this out too: https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc.

Comment: Thanks for your engagement! I did read this page long ago. I had created my own build too - but I made changes only in Java code there (changed some flags to support MediaTek's smoothly, it was not a lot of work).  From what you said, I assume I should create my own wrapper for C++ code which supports open h264 and it should make use of the cisco SO file. Maybe you could give me contact to your friend who could help me figure this out?

Comment: the stack-overflow comment system is no good for me. sorry. for my bad comments. For more professional information you can contact CosMo webrtc (https://www.cosmosoftware.io/) and you can request for all the build and stuffs. I'm sure they can help you get what you want. asking my friend could take some time. but if you insist I can ask anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will surely check it out. Anyways, please let your friend know about this stack-overflow question :) Thanks in advance!