# Using Flutter WebRTC plugin to stream h264 video to Android

Tags: flutter, webrtc, h.264

I am using Janus-Gateway as the server and created an app using flutter WebRTC plugin for the video player. The app works to send VP8 stream to the android device, but when I try to send h264 encoded video it gives an error. From my understanding Android WebRTC doesn't support h264 decoding without hardware acceleration.

But is there a way to force Google's android plugin for webrtc to allow software decoding?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to enable h.264 for WebRTC android like it is for iOS to enable VP8.

WebRTC library provides an interface to use a custom codec, but, you need to compile it on your own.

Here is more info: [Does Google WebRTC support Cisco Open H.264?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766352/does-google-webrtc-support-cisco-open-h-264)

And also here: https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-h264-video-codec-hardware-support/